# How to optimize this C# code

Tags: c#

The below logic is working fine. But is there any way to optimize this logic ?

I have a `string1, string2,...,stringn`
and values of each strings are

`string1 = "s1k1-s1k2-s1k3-....-s1kn | s1v1-s1v2-s1v3-....-s1vn";`

`string2 = "s2k1-s2k2-s2k3-....-s2kn | s2v1-s2v2-s2v3-....-s2vn";`

```
                .............
```

`stringn = "snk1-snk2-snk3-....-snkn | snv1-snv2-snv3-....-snvn";`

Now, I want to populate the `Dictionary<string, string>()` with the key and values as follows.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add(s1k1, s1v1);
dict.Add(s1k2, s1v2);
         :
         :
dict.Add(snkn, snvn);
```

**Below is my sample code:**

```
        string string1 = "s1k1-s1k2-s1k3-s1kn|s1v1-s1v2-s1v3-s1vn";
        string string2 = "s2k1-s2k2-s2k3-s2kn|s2v1-s2v2-s2v3-s2vn";
        string stringn = "snk1-snk2-snk3-snkn|snv1-snv2-snv3-snvn";

        var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        new List<string> { string1, string2, stringn }.ForEach(str =>
        {
            var strSplit = str.Split('|');
            var strKeys = strSplit[0].Split('-');
            var strValues = strSplit[1].Split('-');
            strKeys.Zip(strValues, (key, value) => new { key, value }).ToList().ForEach(filed => dict.Add(filed.key, filed.value));
        });
```

Is it possible to optimize this code interms of Speed and Readability.

Comment: Optimize for what? Speed? Memory consumption? Readability?

Comment: -1: this code does not compile, and even if it did it wouldn't do what you say it does.

Comment: Hey Aneves, What is wrong in this post. You didn't understand the problem.

Comment: Hello @PrasadKanaparthi, welcome to CodeReview. I understood the problem very well. But this is a place to ask for `feedback on a specific _working_ piece of code from your project` - see [the FAQ](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq). Code that has gross syntax and algorithm errors is not "working code". (I personally accept pseudo-code. Others don't.) After you fixed it your code is still missing at least a `);` at the end and **it still does not fill the dictionary**, but that is good enough for me since you are new around here. I removed the -1.

Comment: The problem with the current code is that you're trying to (_very_ wrongly) use `Zip()` to perform side effects (add items to an external dictionary). Not only that, it is never performed because the result of the zipping `temp` is never iterated over which would make it work. However, I would _very strongly_ advise you or anyone from ever doing stuff like that. It will only lead to headaches.

Comment: Hi All, I am new to CR and I just over look all the FAQs. After you guys suggested i read FAQs thoroughly :). Now i have edited my post and corrected my code logic. I really appreciate all your efforts. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to optimize for speed and possibly memory, just use regular loops to build up your dictionary, though it may hurt readability.

The idea is simple, scan the string for keys and values simultaneously.  Don't extract substrings until you know what you need.  Scan each token until you hit a delimiter and add the corresponding keys and values to your dictionary.

Assuming none of your keys or values do not contain any of your delimiters and everything is well formed and you have the same amount of values as you do keys for every string.

```
var myStrings = new[]
{
    "1-2-3-4-5|a-b-c-d-e",
    "10-20-30-40-50|aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd-eee",
};
var delims = new[] { '-', '|' };
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (var str in myStrings)
{
    var sepIndex = str.IndexOf('|');

    var keyStart = 0;
    var valueStart = sepIndex + 1;
    while (keyStart < sepIndex)
    {
        // scan for the end of the token
        var keyEnd = str.IndexOfAny(delims, keyStart);
        var valueEnd = keyEnd < sepIndex
            ? str.IndexOfAny(delims, valueStart)
            : str.Length;

        // extract and add the tokens
        var key = str.Substring(keyStart, keyEnd - keyStart);
        var value = str.Substring(valueStart, valueEnd - valueStart);
        dict.Add(key, value);

        keyStart = keyEnd + 1;
        valueStart = valueEnd + 1;
    }
}
```

---

For readability, a declarative style works well and LINQ is king, just use it better.

```
var dict =
    (from str in myStrings
    let split = str.Split('|')
    let keys = split[0].Split('-')
    let values = split[1].Split('-')
    from pair in keys.Zip(values, (key, value) => new { key, value })
    select pair).ToDictionary(x => x.key, x => x.value);
```

As a side note, don't throw things into a list just for the sake of using the `ForEach()` method, you don't need the overhead of the list just to be able to interate over a collection through that method.

Comment: Hey i just given the scenario with my logic. It works perfectly. But i just want to know is there better way to do that interms of speed and readability.

Comment: @PrasadKanaparthi When I run your code and put a break point after the ForEach statement, the "dict" variable is empty.